# AS2 - How to terminate a conditional test only one level

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

The break statement terminates the whole loop or test, but I want to terminate it only one level. How would you do that?

Comment: provide some code and explanation on what you want to achieve. Do you want to break the code of the current "stage" in your loop or do you want to prevent the next "stage" in your loop? And what kind of loop are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use labels in your for loop. this is as3 but i think it should work in as 2 as well:http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/1228